# Is there a way to fix the vocabulary size for sklearn tfidf_vectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I understand that there is a `max_features` parameter in `sklearn tfidf_vectorizer` that controls the max vocab size.

What I'd like to achieve, is to generate a tfidf_vectorizer that will always give me `N` features. It shall pad `zeros` if the real vocab size is smaller than `N`. And it shall truncate the size down to N if the real vocab size is larger than `N`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using `scikit` API but you could easily write a wrapper over `TfidfVectorizer` yourself to either pad or truncate vectors